# How to extract form data by using automatic filling of field (using python+selenium+chrom webdriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working in python using selenium and web driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

path="E:\Allah Kareem HelpmeGuid me\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://lsg3.nlm.nih.gov/webapps/WebTc.2011/jsp/jdi/vJdi.jsp")

search=driver.find_element_by_name('IN_TERM ')
print(search)
search.send_keys("Glutathione S-transferase-dependent"+Keys.ENTER)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.quit()
```

but I got error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Guide_me\selenum.py", line 9, in 
> search=driver.find_element_by_name('IN_TERM ')   File "E:\Allah Kareem HelpmeGuid
> me\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line
> 496, in find_element_by_name
> return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)   File "E:\Allah Kareem HelpmeGuid
> me\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line
> 978, in find_element
> 'value': value})['value']   File "E:\Allah Kareem HelpmeGuid me\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line
> 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "E:\Allah Kareem HelpmeGuid
> me\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line
> 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"[name="IN_TERM "]"}   (Session info:
> chrome=86.0.4240.75)

please check my code and error
input web page contain only one input and then GO will perform and result will appear in text area
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that i) The element has the name `IN_TERM` ? and ii) There is a space after `IN TERM `? 

If not -- try removing the space at `driver.find_element_by_name('IN_TERM ")`

Comment: Yeah...It should be 'IN_TERM' instead of 'IN_TERM '. I have mentioned the same in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added an extra space at the end of the element's name. Change this line:

```
search=driver.find_element_by_name('IN_TERM ')
```

To this:

```
search=driver.find_element_by_name('IN_TERM')
```

Comment: All you have to do is to click on the green tick mark below the upvote button.

Comment: Plus, accepting an answer as the best answer would gain you 2 points!

Comment: sorry i did not know the rules, that was only for conformation of answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks for replay you
Its only due to one space after IN_TERM

```
search=driver.find_element_by_name('IN_TERM')
```